# Does JavaMail support server-push?

Tags: email, push, jakarta-mail

Does JavaMail support notification of new emails through server-push?

If yes, where is the documentation for that?
If no, is there a library that can do it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be using IMAPFolder's `idle` function to issue the idle command to the server. That will then listen for events, such as a new mail or deleted mail. (See the IMAP spec to see what the messages look like). And you should be using a `MessageCountListener` to execute code when a number of emails in the mailbox change.

IMAP's idle function is exactly meant to imitate "push" functionality.

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/event/MessageCountListener.html
http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html

Sorry I didn't post any code that shows how this is used. I didn't want to waste my time since there are many readily available examples on the internet if you search for this stuff.

But be forewarned, this method won't work for more than one IMAP account since the idle command blocks. Unless you want them all on different threads (bad idea).

Comment: So, if I had 3 Store objects for 3 imap servers, I can't use server push? That's sad :-(

Comment: You can. You have two options. I didn't know how many IMAP connections you were talking about which is why I didn't recommend threads. But if you only want three then the easiest way is to do exactly that, only three threads is nothing at all. Create a thread per IMAP store and issue the `idle` command. Before the `idle` command though make sure to assign a `MessageCountListener` object, then `idle`. Each thread will then handle each of your three accounts. The second more complicated option involves manually managing your sockets, including the reading and writing over them.

Comment: The number "3" was just a random number to explain what I meant. Actually my program will have to deal with thousands of IMAP connections simultanously. I guess that threading is no good idea here.

Answer (score 1):

A Store event listens for notifications issued by your backend store:

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/event/StoreEvent.html

But in my experience the java mail docs are *so* thin in places, that the best way of finding out what is going on, is to debug through the process yourself.

This is a great allround resource as well; the JavaMail FAQ :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html

Comment: Hm, there's nothing in the FAQ about server push :/

Comment: I thought you wanted some way of java mail to listen for notifications sent from your server on mail-arrival. Sorry if I misunderstood!

Comment: Actually, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot for the hint on the StoreEvent. The Store class has a method called addStoreListener(StoreListener l) which can be used to register a listener in order to catch the StoreEvent. The JavaMail FAQ doesn't say anything about it though.

Comment: Are you sure StoreEvent is what you're looking for? I just looked at it and that doesn't look like it notifies on new mail (maybe I'm wrong, but I know my way works). If you want new mail notifications you shouldn't be looking at that. See my answer below...