# JavaMail Store connection: Connect on demand or keep-alive?

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

What does make more sense for JavaMail?

1. Create a Store connection for each request to the email server and then close it immediately after the task has been completed.
2. Open a Store connection and only re-connect if the connection got closed by the server or the local application got terminated.

While (1) can lead to many connect() and close() calls in a row, (2) can block resources although that wouldn't be really necessary (but IMAP/POP3 calls would be fast since no extra .connect() call is required).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Connect on Demand** is better unless you have a requirement to poll the server frequently from a **single** thread.

Comment: So, if I'd wanted to support server push (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389994/does-javamail-support-server-push) then there is no other way than keeping the connection alive, or?

Comment: Yes, there is no other way than keeping the connection alive, but that is only usable for IMAP protocol.