# receiving and handling emails in java

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am working on application that reads input from email and do action according to it.
My application should listen for any new emails and parse it to get attachment file and data inside the body.

My question is: How can I do that in java? how to do that listener in java?
I have an email that I will use to parse received from, but what I want how to listen to any new email and parse data from it.

Comment: What do you mean by listening for email? Do you use your own mail server or public (e.g. gmail)?

Comment: have you looked at [JavaMail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/index.html) ?

Comment: I want to use my own Mail server "exchange" and i have email address at that email ... i want to listen to any new email that will be delivered to that email address and get information and data from it

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4389994/does-javamail-support-server-push

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to take a look at [JAMES](http://james.apache.org/). This offers all the functionality you require.

Comment: thats new mail server ... i am using exchange mail server

Comment: @farajnew - well you might want to update your question to make that clear.