# Javamail doesn't get all mail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to get all mails of my gmail but I can only get 250. According to https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#gmailsettings, I had already set the number of mail limit to 1000 but it still only fetch 250 mails. Here's my code

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.NoSuchProviderException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;

public class Getreply {

  public static void check() {

  String host = "pop.gmail.com";
  String mailStoreType = "pop3";
  String username = "";
  String password = "";
  try {

  //create properties field
  Properties properties = new Properties();

  properties.put("mail.pop3.host", host);
  properties.put("mail.pop3.port", "995");
  properties.put("mail.pop3.starttls.enable", "true");
  Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

  //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
  Store store = emailSession.getStore("pop3s");

  store.connect(host, username, password);

  //create the folder object and open it
  Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
  emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

  // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
  Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
  System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

  for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
     Message message = messages[i];
     Object body = message.getContent(); 
     System.out.println("---------------------------------");
     System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
     System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
     System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
     System.out.println("Text: " + body );

  }

  //close the store and folder objects
  emailFolder.close(false);
  store.close();

  } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (MessagingException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  }

  }
```

Does anyone know how can I get all?

Comment: have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514856/read-mails-again-and-again-from-gmail-using-javamail-api-in-java) ?

Comment: Yes but there will be the same trouble.

Comment: Unless you add specific explanations in your question as to why the answers to that question that Novy linked to did not work for you, this question is going to be closed as duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just test it if you have no need to use pop you should try imap
your chech method will be like this below. Idid test it i can my mails without restriction. But also if you configure your gmail account for a specific number you will receive that number.

```
 public static void check() {

          String host = "imap.gmail.com";
          String username = "user";
          String password = "passwd";
          try {

          //create properties field
          Properties properties = new Properties();


          properties.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
          Session emailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

          //create the POP3 store object and connect with the pop server
          Store store = emailSession.getStore("imap");

          store.connect(host, username, password);

          //create the folder object and open it
          Folder emailFolder = store.getFolder("INBOX");
          emailFolder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);

          // retrieve the messages from the folder in an array and print it
          Message[] messages = emailFolder.getMessages();
          System.out.println("messages.length---" + messages.length);

          for (int i = 0, n = messages.length; i < n; i++) {
             Message message = messages[i];
             Object body = message.getContent(); 
             System.out.println("---------------------------------");
             System.out.println("Email Number " + (i + 1));
             System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
             System.out.println("From: " + message.getFrom()[0]);
             System.out.println("Text: " + body );

          }

          //close the store and folder objects
          emailFolder.close(false);
          store.close();

          } catch (NoSuchProviderException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (MessagingException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
          }
          }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your POP settings in Gmail or switch to IMAP.