# trying to search a mail with subject in Gmail using java

Tags: java, smtp

My company mail domain is Gmail , and I need to search a mail using subject line. I have written below code but Gmail is not connecting with correct user id and password.

```java
     public static void getMail() {
                 Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
                 final String m10 = "abc@abc.com";   
                 final String n10 = "abcd";
                 String host = "absmtp.abc.com"; 
                 try
                 {
                 Properties pro1 = new Properties();   
                 pro1.put("mail.smtp.host", host);    
                 pro1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
                 MailSSLSocketFactory socketFactory= new MailSSLSocketFactory();
                    socketFactory.setTrustAllHosts(true);
                    pro1.put("mail.imaps.ssl.socketFactory", socketFactory);
              //   pro1.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");  
               //  pro1.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");   
                 pro1.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");  
             Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(pro1); 
                 Store store = session.getStore("imaps");  
                 store.connect(host, m10, n10); 
                 Folder folderbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                 folderbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);   
                 SearchTerm search = new SearchTerm(){

                     @Override
                     public boolean match(Message message) {
                         try
                         {
                             if(message.getSubject().contains("") ) 
                             {
                                 return true;
                             }
                         }
                         catch(Exception e)
                         {
                             System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                         }
                         return false;
                     }

                 };

                 Message[] found = folderbox.search(search);

                 int length = found.length;
                 for(int i = 0;i<found.length;i++)
                 {
                     Message mess1 = found[i];
                     System.out.println("->Message Number > "+i);
                     System.out.println("->Message Subject >"+mess1.getSubject());
                 }
                 folderbox.close(true);
                 store.close();
             }
                 catch(Exception e)
                 {
                     System.err.println(e.getMessage());
                 }
                
               }
```

is not connecting and giving error :

> Couldn't connect to host, port: abc@abc.com, 993; timeout -1.

Comment: SMTP is for sending e-mails. When you say "I need to search a mail", it sounds like you are trying to connect to a Gmail inbox instead. Can you clarify?

Comment: yes I am trying to connect the Gmail inbox, can you please tell me what I can use.

Comment: You can use the Gmail API - see [Searching for Messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/filtering). Or you can look at various SO questions (and other tutorials) relating to IMAP and POP access to Gmail using Java. Examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9263530/accessing-emails-from-gmail-using-imap-javamail-api) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33514856/read-mails-again-and-again-from-gmail-using-javamail-api-in-java).